# How does a pro se defendant subpoena digital evidence for the defense?

Tags: criminal-law, canada, process, pro-se

In specific, if partial evidence of blackmail and witness intimidation, (death threats), were to be made public on the web and in direct text, how would the defense go about gaining access to the perpatrators personal digital activity?

Additionally, if there is a way, can further efforts in this vein produce admissible evidence of criminal conspiracy under Canadian law?

If you have any insight, please review my other questions, as they are all part and parcel of one exceptionally surreal matter.

Comment: Editorializing in your questions is not helpful; editorializing in your title is *really* unhelpful.  Asking multiple questions that would have separate answers in a single question post is bad form and will subject your questions to closure.  Begging for attention to your other questions in the content of a question is bad form: Those belong in comments.

Answer (score 1):

You subpoena the evidence from the person who has it. They must either produce it or demonstrate to the court that they don't have it or they are not required by law to produce it (e.g. because it is not sufficiently defined).

Each court system has procedures for how to do this. You can do it yourself (and almost certainly screw it up) or you can hire a lawyer to do it (who is less likely to screw it up).

Doing legal procedures for yourself is *almost* as stupid as doing medical procedures for yourself.

Comment: Just to expand slightly, an attorney can issue a subpoena without specific leave of the court in many circumstances, while a *pro se* party normally has to have a subpoena authorized by the court in advance. The pro se party prepares draft subpoenas for approval by the court which it will usually approve if they are proper in form.